# ANTLR4: Bad Performance when calling getInterpreter().adaptivePredict

Tags: performance, antlr4

Parr and Dear community,

At first I would like to thank you for the amazing Antlr4 (and for antlr as a whole :-) ). 
I have been using Antlr 3 for the last 6 months ( I was already very happy ) but I am even happier with antlr4. I noticed very substantial improvements in grammar simplicity and generation time using java as a target language.
Unfortunately I have some concerns about runtime performance I did not have with antlr3.

Here a excerpt of my grammar:

```
declare_specs
:
DECLARE? declare_spec+
|
DECLARE
;

declare_spec
:
constant_declaration
| variable_declaration
| exception_declaration
| procedure_body
| function_body
;
```

Here the generated code (I added the System.out.println for tracing):

```
    public final Declare_specsContext declare_specs() throws RecognitionException {
            System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 1");
        Declare_specsContext _localctx = new Declare_specsContext(_ctx, getState());
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 2");
        enterRule(_localctx, 118, RULE_declare_specs);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 3");
        int _la;
        try {
            int _alt;
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 4");
        setState(826);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 5");
        switch ( getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,69,_ctx) ) {
            case 1:
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 6");
                enterOuterAlt(_localctx, 1);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 7");
                {

                        if (f_trace >= f_trace_low) {
                            System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - DECLARE_SPECS - FIRST ALT");
                        };

                setState(817);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 8");
                _la = _input.LA(1);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 9");
                if (_la==DECLARE) {
                    {
                    setState(816); match(DECLARE);
                    }
                }

        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 10");
                setState(820); 
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 11");
                _errHandler.sync(this);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 12");
                _alt = getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,68,_ctx);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 13");
                do {
                    switch (_alt) {
                    case 1:
                        {
                        {
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 14");
                        setState(819);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 15");
                        declare_spec();
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 16");
                        }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NoViableAltException(this);
                    }
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 17");
                    setState(822);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 18");
                    _errHandler.sync(this);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 19");
                    _alt = getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,68,_ctx);
        System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - declare_specs - 20");
                } while ( _alt!=2 && _alt!=-1 );
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                enterOuterAlt(_localctx, 2);
                {

                        if (f_trace >= f_trace_low) {
                            System.out.println("TIME: " + timestamp() + " - DECLARE_SPECS - SECOND ALT");
                        };

                setState(825); match(DECLARE);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (RecognitionException re) {
            _localctx.exception = re;
            _errHandler.reportError(this, re);
            _errHandler.recover(this, re);
        }
        finally {
            exitRule();
        }
        return _localctx;
    }
```

Here the traces:

```
................
TIME: 2013-02-06 09:47:10.417 - declare_specs - 12
TIME: 2013-02-06 09:47:11.023 - declare_specs - 13
.................
TIME: 2013-02-06 09:51:38.915 - DECLARE_SPEC - AFTER
.................
TIME: 2013-02-06 09:51:38.916 - declare_specs - 19
TIME: 2013-02-06 09:52:31.435 - declare_specs - 20
...................
TIME: 2013-02-06 09:52:31.435 - DECLARE_SPEC - INIT
```

**I am losing 60'' when calling _alt = getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,68,_ctx); the second time  but less than 1' when calling _alt = getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,68,_ctx); the first time**.
What changed are of course the parameters _input and _ctx.

The problem lies most probably in my grammar but I am at my wits end ;-).
1. Can you may be tell me where I might look for a solution.
2. What is happening in adaptivePredict anyway ;-)

Thank you for your help!

Kind regards, Wolfgang Hämmer

Comment: Sorry, Dear Mr. Parr and Dear Community

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have a decision in your grammar which requires a very large amount of lookahead and/or is ambiguous or context-sensitive. Unfortunately we won't be able to tell you which one without seeing the complete grammar. What you can do is the following which will print out some detailed information about ambiguities to the console.

```
parser.addErrorListener(new DiagnosticErrorListener());
parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION);
```

Comment: Hi Helotes,
thank you for answering!
I've got three kind of error:
1. reportAttemptingFullContext d=nnn, input='xxx'
2. reportContextSensitivity d=nnn, input='xxx'
3. reportAmbiguityd=nnn: ambigAlts={1, n, ...}, input='xxx'

I looked into the code: d is the decision in the DFA, and input is obvious. How can I go from d (decision) to the faulty rule in my grammar? Is it even possible? The code in class 'ParserATNSimulator' is quite complexe.
Thank you for your help!
Kind regards, Wolfgang Hämmer